# Continuous Deployment on Lightsail using SSH

Tags: ssh, continuous-deployment, amazon-lightsail

I recently migrated my hosting environment from Shared Hosting to Lightsail, and I'm facing a challenge with my continuous deployment workflow. Previously, I was using FTP to sync my repository with the directory on my server. However, Lightsail only supports SSH private keys, considering FTP as insecure.
This is the workflow I was using for Github Actions:

```
# Existing workflow on cPanel using FTP
(on: push)
name:  Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
        username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

I need to switch to SSH for deployment. I do not use Docker or any other build tools. I just want to sync the repository when pushing (I'm running the script on local with Laragon).

I tried some tricks but sadly it didn't go well, and most of tricks works with Docker build which I really don't need in my case. I appreciate any help or suggestions.